# chrome.contextMenus in hosted app's local page

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I try to add context menu item to my hosted app. When i add code like this, context menu appears in all pages:

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({
    'title' : 'reload image',
    'contexts' : ['image'],
    'onclick' : function(info, tab) {

    }, 'documentUrlPatterns' : ['<all_urls>']
});
```

But this item is not displayed in my app. When i change documentUrlPattern to:

```
['chrome-extension://extensionId/*']
```

Nothing happens. How can i add context menu item to my hosted app's local page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot inject context menu in any extension page. That is unfortunately limitation. The engineers state it is a security limitation. A search in crbug.com can give you some ideas why.

Comment: well, i have noticed it already (about limitation). but anyway thanks for the link. http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=51461&q=contextMenus&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Pri%20Area%20Feature%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Modified%20Owner%20Mstone%20OS btw it's said here that contextmenus for this scheme will appear in the future

Comment: That's great :) A year later and no activity in that area yet :(